# drag and drop functionality for onhover dropdown tabs using js or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop

I have a condition, where i have menu items on hovering on those menu, child menu's will dropdown.
I want to do drag and drop those child menu in main menu.

can anyone suggest to me how to do that...with any sample code.
I googled but, i didn't find a solution

Thanks

Comment: Please show us what you have and what you have tried. Without the code it's very hard to give you an good answer. Also suggestions of code or samples is off-topic on StackOverflow.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen thanks for the reply, i have used the below w3schools example, its having a drop drop on hover, i want to add drag and drop code to that functionality.                 https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_js_dropdown_hover

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen thanks for the reply, i have used the below example, its having a drop drop on hover, i want to add drag and drop code to that functionality.                  https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/codelab.php?topic=faq&file=make-bootstrap-dropdown-menu-on-hover